# How to extract all the number of views of each video resulted in Youtube search by Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

**What I want:**

- Able to extract all the views of each video resulted by selenium on a youtube search result page.
- For example: if I search for "Believer from Imagine Dragons" on youtube, it should give me the number of views all of the resulted videos have (like - 104M views, 1.5B views, 698M views, etc.) up to let's say for first 20 videos.

**What I have tried**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\chromedriver.exe')
search = 'Believer from Imagine Dragons'
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)

main = driver.find_elements_by_id("metadata")
for datas in main:
    info = datas.find_elements_by_id("metadata-line")
    for views in info:
        view_counts = views.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]""")
        print('view_counts: ' + str(view_counts.text))
```

**Output of this:**

```
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
view_counts: 104M views
```

**What I have also tried**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\chromedriver.exe')
search = 'Believer from Imagine Dragons'
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)


main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "metadata"))
)

data = main.find_elements_by_id("metadata-line")

for datas in data:
    views = datas.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]""")
    print(views.text)
```

**Output of this:**

```
104M views
```

But, none of them gave me what I wanted. Please Help.

**Future Goal (if you could help):**

- Able to play a video which have the highest number of views on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the texts e.g. *TEXT*, from each `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Believer%20from%20Imagine%20Dragons")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#metadata-line span:first-child")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Believer%20from%20Imagine%20Dragons")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='metadata-line']/span[@class='style-scope ytd-video-meta-block' and contains(., 'views')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['1.5B views', '104M views', '32M views', '93M views', '98M views', '2.3M views', '39M views', '26M views', '1.4B views', '9.6M views', '6.7M views', '748K views', '1.3B views', '11M views', '84M views', '51M views', '13M views', '18M views', '197M views', '7.2M views', '79K views', '3.5M views']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: @TejasDhanani Glad to be able to help you out !!! Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?